# How to all unique values in a column have a unique value in adjacent column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel sheet in which the data cannot contain a specified condition or else I will receive an error when I pull the data from the sheet.

The specified condition is that no two cells with the same contents in a specific row can have a different value (**ID**) in the adjacent row. To make this much clearer:

[image: Sheet]

I would like to flag the two rows in the above screenshot due to the *"Valid Name"* in column (`B`) mapping to two separate *IDs* in column (`C`) when these should be the same *ID*.

I have column headings *"Fuzzy Name"* (`A`), *"Valid Name"* (`B`), *"ID"* (`C`) and I would like to flag anytime I have two or more *"Valid Name"s* in column (`B`) that map to two different *"ID"s* in column (`C`).

Answer (score 0):

your best shot COUNTIFS formula, if you data is a "Table":

```
=COUNTIFS([valid name],[@[valid name]],[ID],[@ID])
```

[image]

If not in a table tweak the formula as follows:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2)>1,"Duplicate","OK")
```

[image]

Basically what you are doing here is counting rows that meet two criteria, if you want you can expand it to more criteria.